# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter depends on a registered listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` to show items in a `RecyclerView`. When i call `adapter.startListening();` in my activity's `onStart()` the adapter is empty at run-time. I decided to register a listener to the same query as that of the adapter and pass the list of `Objects` to the adapter's `onBindViewHolder`  and it works perfectly. here's my adapter

```
private void loadList(Query query) {

    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(manager);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Post response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post()
            .setQuery(query, Post.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder(response) {

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position, Post model) {

            //holder.setData(postList.get(position));

            holder.setData(model);

        }

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);

            return new PostViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My adapter is always empty without this registered listener:

```
firestoreListener = query
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Listen failed!", e);
                return;
            }

            postList = new ArrayList<();

            for (DocumentSnapshot doc : documentSnapshots) {
                Post post = doc.toObject(Post.class);
                postList.add(post);
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

Is this how it normally should be done? I thought the query passed to the adapter in the `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` was sufficient and the adapter was going to start listening when i call `adapter.startListening();`

Comment: In which place of your code are you calling `loadList()` method?

Comment: Inside the activity's `onCreate()` method. i create and register the listener on the activity's `onResume()` method.